# PhoneGap on Android: circle and polygon areas act as rectangle in HTML image map

Tags: html, cordova, polygon, geometry, imagemap

I am developing HTML5/JavaScript app. I have one interactive task that uses HTML image map to detect touched areas. On Android 4.0.4. PhoneGap just seems to transform "circle" and "poly(gon)" area types into a rectangle that circumscribes these. Is there a workaround for this or is it just a (probably browser-related) bug?

I found people having same issues on [PhoneGap Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/Ih2j-bedxlI), but without a solution.

Answer (score 0):

HTml

```
<img class="map" src="..." usemap="..." hidefocus="true" />
```

and CSS

```
img.map{
outline: none;
```

}

Comment: The question is about the shape of the map areas, not about visual effects.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting similar problem with the latest android version with webview(not throught phonegap) According WebKit/WebView tap/onclick default highlight (Android Ice Cream Sandwich), it seems like this suggestion should work for you:

```
* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);    
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; /* For some Androids */
}
```

Hopefully this may help you.